# I am using fontAwsome in Vue.js and I am trying to place the icon next to the View Case Study but it is not working. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am having trouble with fontaweoms icon that I want to place next to a text but it is not working and I do not know how to approach that.

```
<div class="box">
        <img src="../assets/project-3.jpg" alt="image">
        <div class="con-text">
            <h2 class = "h2" >View Case Study</h2>
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'eye']" class="fas-fa" />

        </div>
```

This is what I want to do now
however what I have so far is this  I have tried my best to make it work with css but it is not working. Any help is appreciated

[What I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AVsV.png)

[what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mim2e.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
<h2 class = "h2" >
    View Case Study <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'eye']" class="fas-fa" />
</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'eye']" class="fas-fa" />
 <h2 class = "h2" style="display:inline">View Case Study</h2>
```

h2 is a block element, that means it takes the whole row but if you make it display:inline than it becomes an inline element where it takes only the space which it needs.